# SQLAlchemy + Flask: Many-to-many self-referential relationship through a set of tables

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have to extract some information from a weird database and, for that, I need a self-referential many-to-many relationship. Following the tables relations:

```
class A(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'A'

    a_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

class B(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'B'

    a_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(A.a_id), primary_key=True)
    c_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(C.c_id), primary_key=True)

class C(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'C'

    c_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

class D(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'D'

    a_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(A.a_id), primary_key=True)
    c_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(C.c_id), primary_key=True)
```

So, A has another A through B, through C and through D. Following my try to solve that:

```
class A(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'A'

    a_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    another_a = db.relationship('A', secondary='join(B, D, D.c_id == B.c_id).join(A, D.a_id == A.a_id)')
```

As result I'm receiving the following error:

> AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between
>   parent/child tables on relationship Build.promoted_build - there are
>   multiple foreign key paths linking the tables via secondary table '"B"
>   JOIN "C" ON "B".c_id = "D".c_id JOIN "A" ON "D".a_id = "A".a_id'. 
>   Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns
>   which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference from the
>   secondary table to each of the parent and child tables.

Could anyone help me?